# Logic for multivalued search (contains)

Tags: search, logical-operators

[image]

I need to construct some logic according to the above table - where S1, S2 ,S3 are strings and I need to find if the field values (strings) CONTAIN these strings.

Green rows should be returned, red rows not. The list of red and green rows is not exhaustive, but enough that you get the idea.

I feel I am missing a really simple way to do this - any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for something like ` ((Field1 == S1) || (Field1 == S2) || (Field1 == S3)) && ((Field2 == S1) || (Field2 == S2) || (Field2 == S3)) && ((Field3 == S1) || (Field3 == S2) || (Field3 == S3))`

Comment: Exactly. So now I am sure that I had issues translating that to the particular filter syntax of the tool I was using. I feel it's now a pretty dumb question, but I needed to be totally sure I hadn't fluffed the logic. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

((Field1 == S1) || (Field1 == S2) || (Field1 == S3)) && ((Field2 == S1) || (Field2 == S2) || (Field2 == S3)) && ((Field3 == S1) || (Field3 == S2) || (Field3 == S3)) Should be the condition to check this.